# Writing an SVN hook that updates copy of committed code

Tags: bash, svn

I have a SVN repository with a lot of sub-projects stored in it. Right now in my `post-commit` I just loop through all possible folders on the machine and run `svn update` on each:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
DIRS=("/path/to/local/copy/firstproject" "/path/to/local/copy/anotherproject" ... "/path/to/local/copy/spam")
LOGNAME=`/usr/bin/whoami`

for DIR in ${DIRS[@]}
do
    cd $DIR
    sudo /usr/bin/svn update --accept=postpone 2>&1 | logger
    logger "$LOGNAME Updated $DIR to revision $REV (from $REPOS) "
done
```

The problem is that this is slow and redundant when I'm just committing the subfolder of one of the projects. I'm wondering if there's a better way of identifying which of the DIRS I should use and *only* update that one.

Is there some way to do this? As far as I can tell there's no way to determine which part of a repo was committed and thus which directory needs to be updated.

Is the only alternative to create a separate repository for each project? (Probably should have done that from the start, if so...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there's a better way of identifying which of the DIRS
>   I should use and only update that one.

[`svnlook dirs-changed`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svnlook.c.dirs-changed.html) is what you're looking for:

```
# svnlook dirs-changed -r 40270 /path/to/the/repo
project1/foo/bar
```

Try something like this:

```sh
#!/usr/local/bash4/bin/bash

typeset -A IP
typeset -A DOCROOT

PROJECTS="project1 project2"

IP=([project1]="ip1" [project2]="ip2")
DOCROOT=([project1]="/var/www/html/project1/" [project2]="/var/www/html/project2/")

REPO="$1"
REV="$2"

USER='deployer'

PROJECT=`svnlook dirs-changed -r "$REV" "$REPO" | awk -F "/" '{ print $1 }'`

ssh -t "$USER@${IP[$PROJECT]}" "cd ${DOCROOT[$PROJECT]} && svn up"
```

Comment: Oh neat, I think your answer neatly answered another question I had, which was: "Is there such a thing as hash arrays/dicts in bash?" Turns out the answer is **Yes**?

Comment: Yes. [Bash 4](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html) supports associative arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the script I ended up using, based on quanta's help:

```
REPO="$1"
REV="$2"
declare -A PROJECTS
PROJECTS=(\
    [project1]="/path/to/projects/project1 /path/to/projects/project1-devel" \
    [project2]="/path/to/projects/project2 /path/to/projects/project2-devel" \
    [project3]="/path/to/projects/project3 /path/to/projects/project3-devel" \
)

PROJECT=`svnlook dirs-changed -r "$REV" "$REPO" | awk -F "/" '{ print $1 }'`
DIRS=${PROJECTS[$PROJECT]}

for DIR in $DIRS
do
    cd $DIR
    sudo /usr/bin/svn update --accept=postpone 2>&1 | logger
    logger "$LOGNAME Updated $DIR to revision $REV (from $REPOS) "
done
```

Note that the one big thing I had to add was the `declare -A PROJECTS` line. For some reason the associative array/hash wouldn't work until I did this.